# Uploading Files with Ajax working on Postman but not browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, postman

I am trying to let certain users upload a video to the API using Ajax. This works on Postman, but when doing this from the browser I get a 500 Internal Server Error.

I do not have access to the server so I cannot show server logs, but according to the guy that does, he receives the "OPTIONS" post but not the second post with the `multipart/form-data`. When I check my form data in the chrome network tool it gives me [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQYTX.jpg).

And the url I'm appending to for each upload looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owmiU.jpg).

[The two requests in the network tool.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhabD.jpg)

Seems to be something wrong with how my form is being posted and I'm pretty sure it's my fault not the server's since it works with Postman.

The postman code is:

```
var form = new FormData();
form.append("video", "C:\\Users\\Sidhant\\Downloads\\examplevid.mp4");

var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "https://apiurl/catagoryid/videotitle",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "Authorization": "Bearer token",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "Postman-Token": "token"
  },
  "processData": false,
  "contentType": false,
  "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
  "data": form
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

My code is the same except for how I get the file:

```
var fileinput = document.getElementById("fileinput").files[0];
var form = new FormData($('#fileinput')[0]);
```

With postman the video is added to the API, while through the browser it's given a 500 error. How can I stop getting this error, and what are some things I can try. I'm a beginner with Ajax so I'm not familiar with these sorts of issues.

Comment: What is [Object% in your Url? You probably want to append the textbox text to the URL and not the object itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is how you are selecting the files in your formdata.

```
var fileinput = document.getElementById("fileinput").files[0];
var form = new FormData($('#fileinput')[0]);
```

You select the file correctly using plain js, but then use Jquery and simply select the file input element. So it's like you are trying to attach the html element itself, rather than the user data.

Use this.

```
//null check on the input 
var fileinput = $('#fileinput').length ? $('#fileinput')[0].files[0] : null;
//Create the FormData and add the file to the FD
var form = new FormData();
form.append('video', fileinput );
```

Comment: Solved the issue thanks! I see I misunderstood the file selection as you and the other poster pointed out. Unfortunately now I'm running into a 413: payload too large issue, which may be the fault of the server side guy. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

## Problem 1

> ```
> var fileinput = document.getElementById("fileinput").files[0];
> var form = new FormData($('#fileinput')[0]);
> ```

If you initialise `FormData` with a value, it should be a *form element*.

If you want to add a file, you need to create the object and then append the file.

Either way, you shouldn't get the file and then pass it to jQuery. That makes no sense at all. jQuery works with HTML, Selectors and DOM elements, not file objects.

Either:

```
var form = document.getElementById("fileinput").form;
var data = new FormData(form);
```

or

```
var file = document.getElementById("fileinput").files[0];
var data = new FormData();
data.append("video", file, "filename.mp4");
```

## Problem 2

You are overriding the Content-Type of the request, so it won't be generating the correct one from the FormData object and the server won't know how to extract the data.

Delete

> ```
> "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
> ```

and

> ```
> "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
> ```

## Asides

> ```
> "async": true,
> ```

This is the default. There is no point is setting it explicitly.

> ```
> "crossDomain": true,
> ```

This does nothing unless you are making a same origin request which is redirected to be cross origin. There's usually no point in setting it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I see how I screwed up the jQuery element selection. Fixed that issue. I tried your second suggestion however, and it caused the call to fail. I'm not sure why, might be quirk with how the API/server is setup but changing any of the options like content-type, mimeType gives me a 500 error no matter the combination.